# Frequency by letter order

Tags: java, sorting, bufferedreader

I am looking to manipulate a text file through frequency by letter order. In my program there is a method I'm not sure how to start. I'd like to get an output something like:

Letter / Count

1 A     6 ***

2 B     8 ****

3 C     6 ***

(etc.)

To which 6 names begin with A, 8 with B, and 6 with C.
Then an '*' for every 2 count.

My practice problem is actually using a text file with 90000 names and a different '*' count, but an example code and explanation of why it works would be greatly appreciated for my study.

Here's the beginning of my program, but like I said I'm not sure how to start this method whatsoever.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
public class P03Census {
String rec; 
int ctr = 0;


 public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    Object result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a file           name\n(1990 to 2000)\nadd extension",
            "Taylor Daggett", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    String textDoc = (String) result;
    File file = new File(textDoc);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("File name: " +
    file);

    if (!textDoc.endsWith(".txt")) {

        System.out.println("Usage: This is not a text file!");

        System.exit(0);

    } else if (!file.exists()) {

        System.out.println("File not found!");

        System.exit(0);


    }
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String rec;
    int lines = 0;
    int i;


    while((rec = br.readLine()) != null){

        lines++;
        }

        System.out.println("Record count:"+lines);  
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, post what you already tried, and we'll see how we can help you.

Comment: My program is a bit different, and I am not looking for something that fits into my own code. Just an example would be sufficient.

Comment: Do you only care about the first letter of the names, or the count of all letters? And what separates the names in your file?

Comment: Only the first letter.

Comment: Can we presume that your file contains only Strings and no other data types?

Comment: Yes, you can presume that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm that would do what you want, it exploits the fact you can use `char` variables as `int`:

1. First, create an array `int[] letterCount = new int[26]`, which you will use to count the letters.
2. Then, inside the body of your main `while` loop, convert the string `rec` into an array `String[]` where every element is a name. If, in your input file, the names are always separated by the same `char` (like whitespace for example), you could use `String[] names = rec.split(" ")`.
3. Next, run through that `names` in a `for` loop, and check the first letter of each name: `char firstLetter = names[i].charAt(0)`. And use it to increase the count of that letter by one, in the array `letterCount`: `letterCount[firstLetter - 'a']++;`

At the end of the loop, `letterCount` should have the right count. **Note** that if you file contains capital letters, you have to call `rec.toLowerCase()`, at the start of the body of the loop, otherwise you will get out of bounds error, when trying to call `letterCount[firstLetter - 'a']`, or if all names start with upper case, then just replace by `letterCount[firstLetter - 'A']`